# What is publicly known about policy disagreements between generals Bajwa and Faiz Hameed?

Tags: military, policy, pakistan

[According](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-61047736) to the BBC there was a fallout between Chief of Army Staff general Bajwa and his supposed would-be successor general Faiz Hameed, then Director-General of Inter-Services Intelligence. According to the story, Faiz Hameed was marginalized by Bajwa, despite (supposedly) being a favorite of [then] PM Imran Khan. (Khan [seems](https://www.thenews.com.pk/latest/968275-they-were-afraid-i-would-elevate-lt-gen-faiz-to-army-chief-imran-khan-hits-out-at-govt) to deny that was the case, although claims that Faiz Hameed was feared by the then opposition parties, which in the meantime deposed Khan. “I never thought of appointing someone as army chief. [...] They were afraid that I would appoint Lt Gen Faiz. They feared that if that would have happened then it would shatter their future.”)

I'm curious if this is anything more than an interpersonal rivalry issue, or if something is publicly known about some policy disagreements between Bajwa and Faiz Hameed. Bajwa has sometimes taken public positions on some issues e.g. disagreeing with PM Khan. But, on a quick search, I can't find anything on what Faiz Hameed may have said that would have been a challenge to Bajwa in some way. So is anything known about whether they disagreed on any policy issues?

Comment: Better not to consult Indian sources in case of any news about Pakistan and China.

Comment: *What is publicly known about policy disagreements between generals Bajwa and Faiz Hameed?* --- I think, its not possible to know about the disagreement between Faiz and Bajwa. The Army GHQ will not disclose it.

Comment: @Raveesh, *Is Imran Khan an 'Indian source' @user366312?* --- What does that have to do with this question?